# How to convert modded multiplayer world to single player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm switching to single player modded because my friends have lost interest; I've already tried moving the server's "world" folder into the single player's "world" folder, but it seems the way single player handles player data is different than multiplayer, because my inventory is the same however there are no player created houses.

Comment: You want to open a world that was previously opened in a modded game in an unmodified game? That's not a good idea, it will very likely break.

Comment: No, both worlds are using the same modpack. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Who set up the server? Is anything else in the world broken?

Comment: The world is perfectly fine. A friend of mine set up the server but I have access to the console and FTP.

Comment: Then what is your problem?

Comment: When I log into the singleplayer world, there are no player houses, or evidence that players were on the server at all.

Comment: But the inventories are there? What did you do to transfer the world?

Comment: I just copied the world from the server files to singleplayer. Yes, the inventories are there.

Comment: Then that might be a bug with one of the mods. In Vanilla Minecraft it works.

Comment: Sounds like you copied over the player data just fine, but for some reason, created a whole new world when you started in single player. It might help if you gave paths to the files you copied (both server and single player side) and listed the steps you took when you started the world for the first time in single player.

Comment: Again, sorry for not clarifying, but the world is the same, as well position that I was last in in the server. Just no player built structures. As for steps, I downloaded the world from here http://prntscr.com/hawqdk in the FTP, and moved that to my worlds in singleplayer. I don't know if it's relevant since normally i get a message saying the world will have deprecated blocks, but I added a mod or two that the server doesn't have.

Comment: I am in agreement with Tim Post on this one.  It sounds like you transferred the player data but not the chunk data (in the region folder).  With mods, it is also possible that there are chunk errors.  Either way, it sounds like the world is regenerating, which if you transferred level.dat, will be the same seed.  It will regenerate as though no one ever played there.  I recommend focusing your attention on the region folder. DIM1 and DIM-1 folders, as well, as they contain the nether and end [anvil files](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_file_format) which store the chunk data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. What exactly do you think I should do in order to restore the data? And how can I determine if it's the mods or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can find world data in the %appdata%/.minecraft folder. As far as I'm aware, hosted servers with FTP have basically the same folder

Just try and copy the folder where the world data is in, and paste it in your local files, exactly the same place

There is a small chance that you will lose your items in the singleplayer world, but i recommend crafting a temporary chest on the server and putting all of your items in there first, just to be safe. You'll never know when something might break ;)

Hope that helps!